# Place to save playlist in music application after exit

Tags: c#, wpf

I try to create music application and now I am in place where after exit from app I want to save somewhere my playlist to when reopen I have my songs in app.

Where application like winamp save that information ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Isolated Storage API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to read and write files specific to your application under the user's profile directory. You can store the playlist in a file in any format you choose; using .NET serialization would be quickest, using XML or JSON will let you arbitrarily customise the output.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use [Isolated storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy%28v=VS.90%29.aspx). This way is quite easy and transparent. Then you can put some sort of XML into your Isolated storage.
2. Or you can use some sort of in-proc database engines to store your settings. I would recommend using [SQL Server Compact](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/compact.aspx) as it is quite natural to use it in .NET.

So you have two options. If you have little amount of information to store (playlist only), I would select Isolated Storage. And when your application grows and settings become more complicated you could switch to SQL Server Compact.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Isolated Storage feature, see [Introduction to Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "MyApplication")
```

Answer (score 1):

Winamp save the last used playlist in this directory

`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Winamp`

As for your application, I'd suggest that you use the [Isolated Storage API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Application settings](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patrickdanino/archive/2008/07/23/user-settings-in-wpf.aspx) which are stored in the user's profile folder.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how winamp does this, but you can do it in many ways. I would create a xml file, or save it in application settings like Darin Dimitrov says it. with the content i need and save it on windows close event. Open it on application start to "restore" application state.

Answer (score 0):

You can save in a text file or an embedded database like SQLite.

Comment: database is an overkill for such a small amount of data